# datastore error after migrating to python2.7 - works fine on localhost

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I understand that google.appengine.dist was removed from python2.7. What should I use instead?

application works fine on localhost, deployment seems to be successful, but I am getting this message online:

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Here is what my log says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~quick-test/1.368856085074570769/django_bootstrap.py", line 54, in <module>
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
ImportError: No module named dist
```

Here's the line 54 from django_bootstrap.py:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

GAE LAuncher version 1.8.2, had this problem with 1.8 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.7 configuration requires third-party libraries specified in app.yaml, so it might be sufficient to have this in your app.yaml file:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

You can also use webapp2 that includes Django’s templating engine. Version 1.2 included with the SDK is part of App Engine, and you do not need to bundle Django yourself to use it.

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
```

Also, with this code you don't need to call use_library() to explicitly select a Django version:

```
webapp_django_version = "1.2"
```

Comment: had to deploy a few times and flush memcache but now all is working. Thanks!